# Time with a tweet

Tags: php, api, twitter

Asked this accidently as an answer in another thread, (sorry guys, new to the site) we'll try and do it right this time:

I really need to add a date/time, or a unix date to my tweets through my single user Twitter API 1.1 I've searched in vein for an answer to this. All I find everywhere are other people asking the same question.

I've included the posting code below:

```
// Send a tweet
$code = $connection->request('POST', 
$connection->url('1.1/statuses/update'), 
array('status' => "Mindless Test" ));
// A response code of 200 is a success
```

I use twitter for automated control on a non profit web site, in a private twitter account. (Wish they would let private accounts send duplicate tweets.) Adding time will cure it if I can figure out how.

Comment: You want to just add the date to the status? Or you want it to post at that specific time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly it's just a case of adding the date to the status. You can get the current timestamp with `time()`:
// Send a tweet
$code = $connection->request('POST',

```
$connection->url('1.1/statuses/update'), 
array('status' => "Mindless Test".time() ));//Adding timestamp
// A response code of 200 is a success
```

If you want to have a nicer date added you can look into the PHP [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I've been trying to teach myself PHP, but I keep mixing syntax up with the languages I do know. (I forgot the period before time() in all of my attempts) It's working perfectly now. I use twitter with tweetmypc to change camera shots in my goat pen.